# Is the determinantal ideal of the span of a linearly independent set of rank-one matrices radical?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, determinants, ideals, determinantal-ideals

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and let $X_1,\dots, X_n \in M_m(k)$ be rank-one matrices that are linearly independent over $k$. For a fixed integer $1 \leq r \leq m$, consider the ideal $I \subseteq k[t_1,\dots, t_n]$ generated by the $r \times r$ minors of $t_1 X_1+\dots+t_n X_n.$ Is $I=\sqrt{I}$?

If we drop the assumption that $X_1,\dots, X_n$ are rank one, then this is false. Indeed, let $n=m=r=2$, $X_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, and $X_2=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $I=\langle \det(t_1 X_1+t_2 X_2)\rangle=\langle(t_1+t_2)^2\rangle$ is not radical.

Comment: do you have some extra-assumptions on the $X_i$? May they be assumed to be generic among rank $1$ matrices in $M_m(k)$ (instead of just linearly independent)?

Comment: @Libli No, I am more interested to know whether it holds without any genericity conditions. It seems like a plausible generalization of the fact that the determinantal ideal is radical. I am also interested in whether $I$ is prime

Comment: $I$ is certainly not prime without conditions on $n$ (just take $n=m$ and the $X_i = E_{i,i}$, then $I = (t_1t_2...t_n)$.

Comment: The reducedness is a much better question in my opinion. It seems however quite hard without any genericity assumption. Basically, you are asking when specific linear sections of the determinantal varieties are reduced.

Comment: Either your linear sections are generic among the ones defined by rank $1$ matrices and something can be said using deformation theory. Or you can choose the $X_i$ without rank conditions and then they are not necessarily reduced (as you noticed in your example). But the in-between assumption you're making does not look easily usable.